# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not showing in provider list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I installed the latest version of `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` x64 on our Server 2012 machine which is running SQL Server 2012 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

The application installed and is showing in the installed programs list, but when I attempt to run an `OPENROWSET` query, I'm getting

```
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered
```

Additionally, the provider isn't showing up in the list of providers under Server Objects -> Linked Servers -> Providers

I've looked all over the place, but I cannot seem to find any information on how to actually get this to show up in the list.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to show up?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the download page, it's not recommended or supported to load ACE into SQL Server as a linked server provider.

Instead consider using the [SSIS Data Feed Publishing Components for SSIS 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=39931) (or the [Data Streaming Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/data-streaming-destination) for later versions) to load the provider in an isolated, short-lived SSIS process.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with this.  Currently my windows service calls a stored procedure to insert data from an uploaded excel document using `openrowset`.  Will this solution be able to provide the same functionality?

Comment: If you can write an SSIS package to process the file, then you can register the package a View in SQL Server.  Then whenever you SELECT from the view the package will run.

Comment: Additionally, the environment this will delivered to will be a Server 2008, and SQL server 2008.  Will this solution work in that instance?  We are not a normal SQL server shop, we use Oracle, so this needs to work on their servers as well, and the only sql server we have is 2012.

Comment: No, it won't work on SQL 2008.  You could run a SSIS package that loads the data into a table on SQL 2008.

Comment: So, do I have use ACE?

Comment: You could use the Open XML SDK to read the files. https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx